# Facebook graph api returns (#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-test-users

In my facebook app I have 7 test users and all users are mutually friends also.

I have requested this https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token='myTestUserAccessToken'

But it returns

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}

Facebook docs says give Extended Permissions eg:read_stream

I gave it. still getting same error

Comment: Verify permissions: https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=myTestUserAccessToken

Comment: I have resolved it by.. creating test user using graph api.

url : graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=gokul&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN